# Symfony2 EWZRecaptchaBundle never validate recaptcha field

Tags: validation, symfony, bundle, recaptcha

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and I'm trying to use EWZRecaptchaBundle (dev-master) in my registration form. I have followed the steps of [documentation](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle) but it's not work, never validate the recaptcha field.

I've configured the bundle:

```
ewz_recaptcha:
    public_key:  my_public_key
    private_key: my_private_key
    locale_key:  %kernel.default_locale%
```

I've added recaptcha in my class Register:

```
// ...
use EWZ\Bundle\RecaptchaBundle\Validator\Constraints as Recaptcha;

class Register
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @Recaptcha\IsTrue
     */
    public $recaptcha;

    // ...
}
```

and in my RegisterType:

```
// ...
class RegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...  
        ->add('recaptcha', 'ewz_recaptcha');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'register';
    }
}
```

and in my form template:

```
{# ... #}
{{ form_widget(form.recaptcha) }}
{# ... #}
```

But when I submit the form, never validate recaptcha field and never show error message "This value is not a valid captcha." although I don't check it. Is it necessary to do something in the controller that get the form submit?

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, you should probably be aware of the new Recaptcha verson utilizing `I am not a bot` checkbox. Maybe `EWZRecaptchaBundle` does not support it yet?

Comment: Yes, EWZRecaptchaBundle support the new recaptcha version. The issue is in Symfony2 validation, I think.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The key is not to use AJAX. Set the config.yml and the RegisterType as follows:

In app/config.yml you should set the following:

```
ewz_recaptcha:
public_key: public_key_here
private_key: private_key_here
locale_key: '%kernel.default_locale%'
enabled: true
ajax: false
```

Inside the RegisterType you should have:

```
 ->add('recaptcha', EWZRecaptchaType::class,
            [
                'label'       => 'Captcha check:',
                'mapped'      => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Recaptcha()
                ],
                'attr'        => [
                    'options' => [
                        'type'  => 'image',
                        'defer' => false,
                        'async' => false,
                        'size'  => 2
                    ]
                ]
            ])
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest to use gregwar captcha bundle , it is a powerful bundle and easy to use
https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle